# Расположение полей ввода в 2 ряда

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Создаю форму регистрации. Необходимо сделать поля в два ряда. Сейчас они находятся друг под другом:

```css
    #student_form input[type=text],
    input[type=password] {
      height: 44px;
      font-size: 16px;
      width: 45%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      background: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
      border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
      padding: 5px 8px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```html
<div id="student_form">
  <form>
    Много дивов
  </form>
</div>
```

Как их расположить приблизительно так:

```
Первое поле | Второе поле
Третье поле | Четвертое поле
```

и т.д?

Comment: В окне правки есть кнопочка в виде `<>`. Вы ее можете использовать, чтобы вставить код в виде сниппета — тогда он сразу будет исполняться в браузере на странице вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#student_form div:nth-child(odd) {
  float:left;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="student_form">
  <form>
   <div>Первое поле</div>
    <div>Второе поле</div>
    <div>Третье поле</div>
    <div>Четвертое поле</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

для  первых div в строчке ( и будет вам счастье):

```
float: left;
```

Comment: Вам тоже предложу обратить внимание на возможность добавлять код в виде сниппета. :)